# c++ to c# MIXERCAPS structure

Tags: c#, c++, struct

How do you convert this struct from c++ to c#?

```
typedef struct {
  WORD      wMid;
  WORD      wPid;
  MMVERSION vDriverVersion;
  TCHAR     szPname[MAXPNAMELEN];
  DWORD     fdwSupport;
  DWORD     cDestinations;
} MIXERCAPS;
```

I've started but I'm kind of stuck on MMVERSION and szPname[MAXPNAMELEN]. This is what I've got now

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
struct MIXERCAPS
{
public ushort vMid;
public ushort wPid;
    //<< MMVERSION
public int vDriverVersion;
    //<< missing? [MAXPNAMELEN]
public string szPname;
public UInt32 fdwSupport;
public UInt32 cDestinations;
}
```

Comment: MMVersion = UInt, szPname = public fixed char szPname [MAXPNAMELEN];

Comment: What is the type of MMVERSION? I am assuming that is a #define or typedef statement somewhere. Also, how are you planning to use this, do you need to pInvoke into some dll from your c# or are you trying to reimplement something? A quick search of [pInvoke.Net](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/Structures/MIXERCAPS.html) turned up this result.

Comment: @pstrjds thanks for the pInvoke, yeah I'm trying to use the new windows sdk

Answer (score 1):

From pInvoke

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
struct MixerCaps
{
  public ushort ManufacturerID;        
  public ushort ProductId; 
  public int Version;          
  [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst=32)] 
  public String ProductName;
  public uint Support;
  public uint Destinations;        
  public override String ToString()
  {
 return String.Format("Manufacturer ID: {0}, Product ID: {1}, Driver Version: {2}, Product Name: \"{3}\", Support: {4}, Destinations: {5}", ManufacturerID, ProductId, Version, ProductName, Support, Destinations);
  }
}
```